# Is there a PostgreSQL equivalent of SELECT @@ROWCOUNT in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, postgresql, rowcount

Question says it all. Any help with working sample much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This command allows retrieval of
>   system status indicators. Each item is
>   a key word identifying a state value
>   to be assigned to the specified
>   variable (which should be of the right
>   data type to receive it). The
>   currently available status items are
>   ROW_COUNT, the number of rows
>   processed by the last SQL command sent
>   down to the SQL engine, and
>   RESULT_OID, the OID of the last row
>   inserted by the most recent SQL
>   command. Note that RESULT_OID is only
>   useful after an INSERT command into a
>   table containing OIDs.

```
GET DIAGNOSTICS integer_var = ROW_COUNT;
```

[Ref](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/plpgsql-statements.html).